# In SSIS 2008 R2, can I use package variables for the server and the database name in a Connection Manager?

Tags: ssis

I would like to this so I can deploy SSIS packages through a normal development progression Development > UAT > Production. The application I am using has the each environments database on different server and uses a different name database in each environment.

Comment: If you are using an `SSIS 2008,` then you will have to rely on configurations to dynamically set the connection strings. You can use package variables, but those variables will have to be configured.(In your case I think, you can do using SQL configuration.).Those are not as convenient as the parameters in `ssis 2012`.

Comment: My "go to" article on classic package configuration [Defining a Configuration Approach for Integration Services Packages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc671625.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll have to choose one of the 'package configuration' options.

Go to the SSIS > Package Configurations... menu to start the wizard.  From there you will start by adding a new configuration.  Next, you will choose the type from these options: XML file, Environment variable, Registry Entry, parent package variable or SQL server.

From here you can choose your variables, connections, etc. to save in whatever configuration type you choose.  You will be able to save down to the connection string level for each connection manager if you want.

My example:

I have used the SQL server option.  You must have a connection manager to use when setting this up to create and read the configuration table.  I set up a connection manager as 'localhost' so that each server it is installed in, it will read the configuration table from the local database.

All the configurations are loaded from that db table when the package runs.

Whichever method you choose, you will have to deploy something to each server along with your dtsx package (an xml file, db table, etc.) but at least you won't have to build multiple versions of the package.

Comment: Nicko66 Thank you, you have got me on the right track. I have since used the SQL server option and now have data driven connections. I have not used the localhost but have create a new SSIS_Configurations database on each server. The existing Connect Managers now use a variable in the Expression property, that hold the connection string. The variables get their connection strings at start up from this new database.